# How to add before send function to current return ajax function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

i have a main form on my main page, the form get an email address from the user and check if the email exist.

My target is to show the results on the same page with bootstrap collapse.
I am using this code in the javascript side:

```
$(".emailCheckForm").bind("submit", function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        width: "auto",
        height: "auto",
        padding: 10,
        cache: !1,
        url: "_/php/checkemail.php",
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        success: function (t) {
            $(".res").append(t).collapse();
        },beforeSend: function(){
        $( "#message" ).empty();
    }
    }), !1
}),
```

my html code:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="col-md-8 centered emailCheckForm"> 
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control checkFrame" placeholder="you@youremail.com">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <input type="submit" value="answer me!" class="btn btn-default checkFrame" tabindex="-1" />
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.input-group -->
    </form>
    <div class="res"></div>
```

Now this working but the problem is that if i want to check another email i get the same results until i will refresh the page.

So i want to implement a before send function that will remove\empty the div results.
I cant make this happen because that every time that i insert the beforsesend function the post not working, any suggestions to make proccess like that in the right way?

Comment: Why don't you include the code _with_ the `beforesend` function in it?

Comment: call this before ajx http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: Ok i updated the question with the beforesend

Answer (score 0):

How about this one. On every successful callback it will clean up results from previous request and re-populate latest:

```
...
success: function (t) {
     $(".res").empty().append(t).collapse();
}
...
```